# How MVC works in magento

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

Thanks for the previous replies.

I am new to Magento and don't know how MVC operates in this framework. I want to display "Hello world" using MVC format--i.e., the controller imports the string from the model and transmits it to the view for display. Can anyone give me an idea of how MVC works in Magento?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This [Magento MVC flowchart](http://alanstorm.com/2009/img/magento-book/magento-mvc.png) may assist

Answer (score 2):

you can take the magento basics course for free today http://www.magentocommerce.com/services/on-demand

Answer (score 2):

The only thing different in Magento's MVC model that is different from other MVCs is the way it use Block.
In normal MVC, variables are passed to the View through Controller. However, in Magento, Views get data from Block, and Block gets its data from Model.

Answer (score 2):

As we know, the implementation of a “Tier Model” is a large part of an MVC framework. It represents the details of your application and handles data in applications. Magento Models play an even greater role, because they usually contain the “Business Logic”.

The Magento Object Relational Mapping (ORM) has very important role in the process of working with database. Here We will go deeply to understand ORM. You can follow:

- [Magneto Object Relational Mapping ORM](http://www.phpzag.com/magento-object-relational-mapping-orm/)
- [MVC Developers - Magneto Models and ORM Basics](http://blog.onlinebizsoft.com/mvc-developers-part-4-magento-models-and-orm-basics)